# Missing Argument / issues opening GUI program on macOS Big Sur

Tags: python-3.x, macos, user-interface, tkinter

This is my first GUI program and I am having some major issues. I really need some help.  First, I cannot get the program to open on my computer (mac). When running in Idle IDE I get this error message:     import Tkinter
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'.

I have 3.9 installed which I thought had a GUI interface.

When debugging in VS Code i get this error message @ line 44:
Exception has occurred: TypeError
**init**() takes at least 4 arguments (3 given)

I think I have 4

I'm not sure where to begin with these issues. From my research it appears that there is an issue running GUI programs on macs updated higher then 11.1.

Code is below

```
# Create a Tkinter GUI program that converts Celsius Temp to Fahrenheit
# F == Fahrenheit
# C == Celsius
# Tkinter imported
import Tkinter

# Global variable used
temp_val = 'Celsius'

#Set value for drop down menu 
def store_temp (set_temp):
    global temp_val
    temp_Val = set_temp

class TemperatureConverter:
    def __init__(self):
    
    # create main window
      self.main_window = Tkinter.Tk()

    # create a title for window
      self.main_window.title('Temperature Converter')

    # create three frames
      self.top_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
      self.option_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
      self.mid_frame = Tkinter.Frame()
      self.bottom_frame = Tkinter.Frame()

    #create widget for top frame
      self.prompt_label = Tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, text= 'Enter a temperature in Celsius: ')

    #pack top frame
      self.prompt_label.pack(side='left') 

    # create  str variable obj to hold empty string variable
      self.inputNumber = Tkinter.StringVar()
      self.var = Tkinter.StringVar()   

    # create widget for option drop down menu  
      self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self.option_frame, textvariable=self.inputNumber )
      self.dropDownList = ['Celsius','Fahrenheit']
      self.drop_down = Tkinter.OptionMenu(self.option_frame, value=self.var , values=self.dropDownList, command=store_temp)
      self.var.set(dropDownList[0])

    # option widgets packed
      self.entry.pack(side='right')
      self.dropDownList.pack(side='left')

    #create widget for middle frame   
      self.result_label = Tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame) 

    # create widgets for bottom frame
      self.call_convert = (call_convert , result_label, inputNumber)

      self.convert_button = Tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text='Convert', command=self.call_convert)

      self.quit_button= Tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text= 'Quit', command= self.main_window.destroy)

    #pack the buttons
      self.convert_button.pack(side='left')
      self.quit_button.pack(side='left')

    #pack the frames
      self.top_frame.pack()
      self.option_frame.pack()
      self.mid_frame.pack()
      self.bottom_frame.pack()

    #Enter the tkinter main loop
      Tkinter.mainloop()

    # convert method is callback fucntion for convert button
      def call_convert(self):
          if temp_Val == 'Celsius':

              f = float((float(temp)* 9/5)+32)
              self.result_label.config(text='The temperature in Fahrenhiet is:')

          if temp_Val == 'Fahrenheit':

              c = float((float(temp)-32) * 5 / 9)
              self.result_label.config(text='The temperature in Celsius is:')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    temp_converter = TemperatureConverter()
```

Comment: If it is Python 3.x, `Tkinter` should be `tkinter`.

Comment: There are alot of errors in your code, I recommend taking a basic tkinter tutorial first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a lot of bugs in your code. I fixed all of them (I think). I had to guess where you wanted to put the label with the results. I also had to fix all of the indentations. This is the working code:

```py
# Create a tkinter GUI program that converts Celsius Temp to Fahrenheit
# F == Fahrenheit
# C == Celsius
# tkinter imported
import tkinter

class TemperatureConverter:
    def __init__(self):
        # create main window
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        # create a title for window
        self.main_window.title("Temperature Converter")

        # create three frames
        self.top_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.option_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.mid_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)
        self.bottom_frame = tkinter.Frame(self.main_window)

        # create widget for top frame
        self.prompt_label = tkinter.Label(self.top_frame, text="Enter a temperature in Celsius:")

        # pack top frame
        self.prompt_label.pack(side="left")

        # create str variable obj to hold empty string variable
        self.inputNumber = tkinter.StringVar(self.main_window)
        self.var = tkinter.StringVar()   

        # create widget for option drop down menu  
        self.entry = tkinter.Entry(self.option_frame, textvariable=self.inputNumber)
        self.dropDownList = ["Celsius", "Fahrenheit"]
        self.drop_down = tkinter.OptionMenu(self.option_frame, self.var, *self.dropDownList)
        self.var.set(self.dropDownList[0])

        # option widgets packed
        self.entry.pack(side="right")
        self.drop_down.pack(side="left")

        # create widget for middle frame   
        self.result_label = tkinter.Label(self.mid_frame) 

        # create widgets for bottom frame
        self.convert_button = tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Convert", command=self.call_convert)

        self.quit_button= tkinter.Button(self.bottom_frame, text= "Quit", command=self.main_window.destroy)

        # pack the buttons
        self.convert_button.pack(side="left")
        self.quit_button.pack(side="left")

        # pack the frames
        self.top_frame.pack()
        self.option_frame.pack()
        self.mid_frame.pack()
        self.bottom_frame.pack()

        # It is better to call `<tkinter.Tk>.mainloop()`
        self.main_window.mainloop()

    # convert method is callback fucntion for convert button
    def call_convert(self):
        if self.var.get() == "Celsius":
            f = float((float(self.entry.get())* 9/5)+32)
            self.result_label.config(text="The temperature in Fahrenhiet is: "+str(f))
        if self.var.get() == "Fahrenheit":
            c = float((float(self.entry.get())-32) * 5 / 9)
            self.result_label.config(text="The temperature in Celsius is: "+str(c))
        self.result_label.pack(side="bottom")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    temp_converter = TemperatureConverter()
```

Look at what I did for the `OptionMenu` and look at how I fixed you `call_convert` function. If you have any specific questions, tell me and I will try to answer them.

By the way I don't think any of the errors you were getting were caoused by your OS. Also I suggest that next time you use `import tkinter as tk` as it will make it way easier to write code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I see the differences made when you utilize * in the options menu, I also see the change made to the call_convert function. Just so I understand correctly there is no reason to use value= or values= when using OptionMenu.

Comment: @stay_caffinated_always If this is the answer you were looking for please accept it so that other people don't waste time answering it as well.